# Display flickering when HDMI is connected

Tags: display, hdmi

I have an ATI Radeon HD 5700 graphics adapter which I am trying to connect to a TV and a monitor.

With only the monitor connected everything works fine, however as soon as I plug in the HDMI cable going to the TV the screen begin to flicker.

I have updated the system bios and the graphics driver and the problem remain.

The screen flickers during POST and in boot up menus when the cable is connected so the issue doesn't seem related to the os (win xp) or my drivers.

The flicker may remain even after detaching the hdmi cable and require me to disconnect the computer from the mains to get it working normally again.

When connecting my laptop using the same cable to the tv in question, the laptops display does not flicker. So the tv and the cable should also be ok.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue, is it a broken gfx adapter or can it be something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to guess that it is a hardware problem or technical software setting? Do you have a VGA cable because you could try that and see if that works? It will give you slightly less quality if you are trying to play blurays or something however. You should also try checking the refresh rates. If it is too high or low it may be causing the flickering. You should be able to experiment with this by right clicking the desktop and going to 'graphic properties'. There are also a lot of other settings in this panel that you can try playing around with. Check the specs of the TV to make sure you our outputting the correct refresh rate. If you make any headway, then post here again and I will see if that helps me any in diagnosing your problem. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the tv does not have a vga in so trying a vga cable doesn't work.

I have tried locking the display refresh rate to 60 but it doesn't help.

The tv doesn't flicker, its the monitor and only when the tv is connected or when the tv has been connected.

Have tried all settings I can find but no success so I think I'll give up and only have the hdmi cable connected when actually watching something on the telly.

Comment: Oh, sorry...Wish I could be of more help. These types of things are really technical. I know when I connect via VGA from my laptop to my big TV it has issues displaying it properly! It took me like an hour to fix it, grrr... :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is most likely that the basic speed on core and memory (157/300) does not provide enough power for the hdmi output.

Dirty FIX: put something else playing on desktop meanwhile, so the gpu automatically up's the core and memory speeds higher.

If you find better solution - please, let me know.

PS. Ofcourse you can always reprogram the GPU Bios, but that seems a bit harsh move for dealing with an issue such as this.

It's the infamous "desktop clock speed" problem all over again.